# How to extract the names from a "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" in bash

Tags: bash

My input data formatted as the pattern '<name> <a>/<b>'. It is possible occurs zero or many times in the same line. And it is possible exist a extra space between the '/'.

I expect to extract the names as

```
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

Here is the wrong code

```
echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" \
 | grep -o -E '\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9. ]+\b'))
```

will extract

```
name1 11
name2 33
name3 last3 55
```

This script should also pass empty line as no output.

Comment: In your grep pattern, the space is killing you (`[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+`).  When `grep` starts to match `name3`, this pattern consumes all subsequent alphanumerics, but also all periods and spaces. If you just use `[a-zA-Z0-9.]+`, you get just name1 name2 name3 last3, but each on a separate line of course (as this is how `grep -o` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" | 
    awk -F' *[0-9]* */ *[0-9]* *' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i}'
name1
name2
name3 last3

$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" | 
    awk -F' *[0-9]* */ *[0-9]* *' -v OFS='\n' '{NF-=1}1'
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of {NF-=1} and the postfix 1?

Comment: The first method works, the second method can not process empty line case

Comment: @DanielYCLin: to ignore empty lines change it in `.... '!/^$/{NF-=1}1'` or `... /^$/{next} {NF-=1}1'`

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` you could easily extract the `<a>/<b>` parts:

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" |
  grep -oE '[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+'
11/22
33 / 44
55/66
```

But as what you want is not to print these but replace them with newlines, `sed` or `awk` are probably better choices. Example with `sed`:

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" |
  sed 's![[:space:]]*[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*!\n!g'
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" |
  sed -E 's!\s*\S+\s*/\s*\S+\s*!\n!g'
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

Note that a newline is also added after the last name of a line, leading to empty lines in the output. If this is not acceptable we can process the last name of a line separately. Example with GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" |
  sed -E 's!\s*\S+\s*/\s*\S+\s*$!!;s!\s*\S+\s*/\s*\S+\s*!\n!g'
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

With `awk` we can define the field separator as the `<a>/<b>` parts you want to remove and print all fields (except the last empty field) on a separate line:

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" |
  awk -F '[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*' '
    {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i}'
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

Or, with GNU `awk`:

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" |
  awk -F '\\s*\\S+\\s*/\\s*\\S+\\s*' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i}'
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE) option, would you please try:

```
echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" \
 | grep -oP '\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9. ]+\b(?=\s+\d+\s*/\s*\d+)'
```

Output:

```
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

`(?=\s+\d+\s*/\s*\d+)` is the lookahead assertion which matches
a sequence of:

- one or more blank character(s)
- one or more digit(s)
- zero or more blank character(s)
- a slash character
- zero or more blank character(s)
- one or more digit(s)

The matched substring is not included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `\s/\S`, this might be what you want:

```
$ echo "name1 11/22 name2 33 / 44 name3 last3 55/66" | 
    awk -v RS='\\s+\\S+\\s*/\\s*\\S+\\s*' 'RT'
name1
name2
name3 last3
```

Comment: can not work, I've tested on debian mawk 1.3.4

Comment: @DanielYCLin it absolutely DOES work **Using GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and \s/\S** as I stated in my answer and you can see it working in my answer. Not following the instructions in an answer and then downvoting it because you didn't do that is not a good way to continue to get help on this forum.